# Can't connect to Database (ITS AUTO COMMENTING)

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I had an VPS with Portal using MySQL and PHP. So today I tried to install it on my local PC with WAMP.
I couldn't connect to my database so I made test.php and here is the problem:

The Code:
http://www.igreklik.com/slike/images/41599508267923822489.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php
    include 'js/konekcija.php';
  ?>
  <body>
    <?php
      $counter = 1;
      $proveripari = mysql_query("SELECT pIme, pPari FROM igraci ORDER BY pPari DESC LIMIT 10 ;"); 
      if( mysql_num_rows($proveripari) > 0)
      {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($proveripari))  
        {
          $counter2 = $counter++;
          echo($row['pPari']);
        }
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page when I try to open:
http://www.igreklik.com/slike/images/99283424889650387796.png
(It shows half of the code, the other half is commented)

You see there is an comment which isn't written in the code, so basically that's why it doesn't shows any errors when I try to connect to the database and that's why I can't show what my database contains...

Comment: Sorry, please post your code here, not some link to some screenshot. Always make things easy for us if you want an answer, not for you yourself.

Comment: I thought adding screenshot is better and more easy to read btw for me the easiest way to do this was to post the code instead making screenshots because those screenshots i've made were edited in paint and uploaded so i bassicly fcked more time than posting the code so i dont agree with you...

Comment: Sorry, we don't have to discuss this. There are clear rules how to post here. Post your code, not a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if there is that kind of rule which suckz but here is the CODE...

Comment: @WoodyMKD I guess you are entitled to your own opinion but it doesn't make sense to post code as a screenshot. Usually, if the mistake isn't obvious, people would like to copy the code into their editor to see if any error reporting kicks off, or debug the code/output. Only having a screenshot adds a lot of extra work for the people trying to help.

Comment: Sorry, but you claim "Cant connect to Database", yet your code contains no attempt of a connection at all! It only uses an already existing connection, as far as I can see. If that connection code is inside the included file, how are we meant to guess its content?

Comment: To me this looks like your local http server is not setup to interpret php.

Comment: @arkascha That was my first problem but in this case connecting to database isn't problem. The problem is why is the browser commenting my PHP code. I have wamp, so how can i setup my local http server to interpret php... Any ideas, solutions, links etc ?

Comment: When connecting to the database is not a problem, then why do you claim so in your questions title? Sorry, but you waste time of people trying to help you by not putting effort into phrasing your question such that it is clear what you ask. I am out.

Comment: I said i couldn't which means i couldn't in the past and after that part i try to explain why i thought that i couldn't connect to my database and why im asking for help...

Answer (score 1):

You must use the server address and not the absolute file path. Use `http://localhost/APP/blah.php` rather than `file:///C:/wamp/www/APP/blah.php`. The absolute path cannot execute the php code. The server path will execute the php code. Paste your php codes and project files in the `www` folder of the WAMP installation directory and then open it using the localhost address as it looks from your snapshot that you have not put your files in the www folder at all.